# Suggestion chips for display devices

Tags: actions-on-google

We're developing a google actions project for smart display devices, and are fining the behavior of suggestion chips rather unintuitive. They fade away after some period of time, which I think could confuse users. On the phone the chips stick around. Are there any setting that can alter this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for a developer to change the behavior of a suggestion chip's visibility. The behavior on a given surface is the only behavior that can happen.